# Select based on child of child with condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have a user who owns a list of houses and all houses have a list of dishwashers.

Now, I want to get a list of users which have a dishwasher by the name "Siemens".

How do I write something in LINQ that can do that?

My current attempt looks like this:

```
users = db.Users
          .SelectMany(u => u.Houses)
          .SelectMany(h => h.Dishwashers)
          .Where(d => d.Name=="Siemens");
```

Comment: It returns a list of dishwashers rather than a list of users, so sadly it doesnt  work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter using `Any` instead of trying to select all of them

```
var users = db.Users
    .Where(u => 
        u.Houses.Any(h => 
            h.Dishwashers.Any(d => 
                d.Name == "Siemens"
            )
        )
    ).ToList();
```